# External Id not an option for custom field

Tags: salesforce

I'm working on a data integration project with Salesforce.  All of the objects I'm working with I've been able to add a custom field and flag it as External Id in the "General Options" section of the custom fields.  Except this one object, the option is not available.

Comment: Standard? Custom? From a managed package! Have you run of ext id fields on this object, I think the limit is 3 or so?

Comment: Custom, possibly from a managed package (was developed by external contractor) not sure how to tell.  There are no extid fields on the object.

Comment: The object is knowledge_kav, it's listed in object manager as "Custom Object" but I also see reference to that object in SF API docs.